# Scale/transform object with path in PSD

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I need to make composites of 2-3 images and create a new image. Let's say product shot 1 is a table, 2 is the table legs, 3 is the hardware. I need to make a new image of all of these components in one image, as well as keep the originals.

These individual shots all have vector paths, and all need to be scaled about 50% to make them all fit on the same size canvas.
I can transform the images, and I can transform the path, but these are separate operations. 
Is there a way to transform the object with the path "linked"?
I've converted my object to a smart object, tried converting the path to a selection, moving and scaling, then converting back to vector path but I lose so much integrity of the path that it's not an option. 
CC 2018 19.1 for Mac OS 10.11.6

Answer (score 1):

If the object is in a layer, apply the transformation in the object or in the path, this is indifferent, and then select the path or the object and press <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and exactly the same transformation will be applied to the next object/path

[image]

This applies for any kind of transformation: scale, move, rotate, skew, etc. If you need to just move an object, instead of moving it with the Move Tool, do it with a transformation frame and then apply the transform again shortcut to the other object/path.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that shortcut! I can successfully transform them using scale, so I can input mathematically the exact reduction for both, but the trouble comes if I need to move the object somewhere else on the canvas. It's sort of artistic and I have to play around to make them fit... There has to be a better way than "move object, then nudge path to match"

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: OMG I was doing this in steps as a sequence. I can scale and move object, then apply the transformation to path with one keystroke, which I will now automate, since I have HUNDREDS of these to do! Danielillo, thank you so so much!